# adding radioswissjazz to rythmbox

Tags: rhythmbox, internet-radio

I tried  and pasted the stream link http://www.radioswissjazz.ch/live/aacp.m3u 
but i cannot have it play: Always in 'paused'

same for http://tamtamdesiles.ice.infomaniak.ch/tamtamdesiles.mp3

what am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help

Guy

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- copy link
- in Rhythmbox, goto "Music" > "New Internet Radio Stream"
- paste link
- click "add"

Under "Radio"you have now Genre "unknown". You will find your newly added link here.
If you doubleclick it, it will be opened and put under Genre "Jazz Music".

- now click on "Jazz Music" Genre.
- select your link
- press play

Music should start playing. 
At least it did here. Using Rhythmboy 2.96 under ubuntu 12.04.